# Very simple program passes VS2010 c++ memory leak checker, but still uses more memory at program end after destroying all objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, stl, memory-leaks

I've been having trouble with a memory leak in a large-scale project I've been working on, but the project has no leaks according to the VS2010 memory checker (and I've checked everything extensively).

I decided to write a simple test program to see if the leak would occur on a smaller scale.

```
struct TestStruct
{
    std::string x[100];
};
class TestClass
{
public:
std::vector<TestStruct*> testA;
//TestStruct** testA;
TestStruct xxx[100];
TestClass()
{
    testA.resize(100, NULL);
    //testA = new TestStruct*[100];
    for(unsigned int a = 0; a < 100; ++a)
    {
        testA[a] = new TestStruct;
    }
}
~TestClass()
{
    for(unsigned int a = 0; a < 100; ++a)
    {
        delete testA[a];
    }
    //delete [] testA;
    testA.clear();
}
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    char inp;

    std::cin >> inp;
    {
        TestClass ttt[2];
        TestClass* bbbb = new TestClass[2];
        std::cin >> inp;
        delete [] bbbb;
    }
    std::cin >> inp;

    std::cin >> inp;
    return 0;
}
```

Using this code, the program starts at about 1 meg of memory, goes up to more than 8 meg, then at the end drops down to 1.5 meg.  Where does the additional .5 meg go?  I am having a similar problem with a particle system but on the scale of hundreds of megabytes.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

As an aside, using the array (which I commented out) greatly reduces the wasted memory, but does not completely reduce it.  I would expect for the memory usage to be the same at the last cin as the first.

I am using the task manager to monitor memory usage.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the difference between reserved and committed memory?

Comment: @ildjarn No, I do not.  But I can guess from the name, that the program is assuming it will need a certain amount because of heavy usage?  Does that mean the program is not actually using that much memory?

Comment: That depends which column you're looking at in task manager, and what version of Windows you're running. You should use an actual memory profiler rather than task manager if you want consistent and meaningful numbers.

Comment: The column says, "Memory (Private Working Set)".
I use Windows 7 professional x64.

Comment: Here is a SO recommended series on memory leaks: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx

It will help you understand how memory is used and explain the different kinds (reserved, committed) of memory.

Comment: If you're particle effects are leaving behind a footprint reservation of hundreds of megabytes your peak working set is probably well over 12 GB which means you may be "doing it wrong™" in the first place as well ...

Comment: I am using 30k particles per emitter with 100's of emitters and each particle stores a large amount of data for simulation.  I don't go anywhere near 12 GB, though.

Thanks for the article.

Answer (score 1):

*"I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong."*

Probably nothing.

*"[Program] still uses more memory at program end after destroying all objects."*

You should not really care about memory usage at program end. Any modern operating system cares about "freeing" all memory associated with a process, when the process ends. (Technically speaking, the address space of the process is simply released.)

Freeing memory at program end can actually slow down the termination of your program, since it unnecessarily needs to access memory pages which may even lie on swap space.

That additional 0.5MB probably remains at your allocator (malloc/free, new/delete, std::allocator). These allocators usually work in a way that they request memory from the operating system when necessary, and give memory back the OS when convenient. Fragmentation could be one of the reasons why the allocator has to hold more memory than strictly required at a moment in time. It is also usually faster to keep some memory in reserve, since requesting memory from the operating system is slow.

*"I am using the task manager to monitor memory usage."*

Measuring memory usage is in fact more sophisticated than observing a single number, and it requires good understanding of virtual memory and the memory management between a process and the operating system. Unfortunately I cannot recommend any good tools for Windows.

Overall, I think there is no issue with your simple program.